# Change Text encoding and view file

Tags: text, encoding

Below text is produced in windows. The file has no extension but is procuded in program like notepad. So i want to convert to readable and pass to powerpoint using vba. The problem is that is non readable. Contains english and greek letters.
Τried to change the text encoding but it did not work. It continues to be non readable

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1253\cocoartf1561\cocoasubrtf610
{\fonttbl\f0\fswiss\fcharset0 Helvetica;\f1\fswiss\fcharset0 ArialMT;\f2\froman\fcharset0 Times-Roman;
}
{\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;\red255\green0\blue0;}
{\*\expandedcolortbl;;\csgenericrgb\c100000\c0\c0;}
\paperw11900\paperh16840\vieww12000\viewh13320\viewkind0
\deftab720
\pard\tx1560\tx1843\pardeftab720\partightenfactor0

\f0\b\fs20 \cf0 FOGR93 LGTS 0
\f1 1
\f0 0330
\f1 \

\f0 \ul \uc0\u928 \u929 \u927 \u915 \u925 \u937 \u931 \u919  \u922 \u913 \u921 \u929 \u927 \u933  \u913 /\u916  \u920 \u917 \u931 \u931 \u913 \u923 \u927 \u925 \u921 \u922 \u919 \u931 \
\pard\pardeftab720\partightenfactor0

\f1 \cf0 \ulnone \

\f0 \ul \
\uc0\u917 \u928 \u921 \u922 \u921 \u925 \u916 \u933 \u925 \u913  \u934 \u913 \u921 \u925 \u927 \u924 \u917 \u925 \u913 
\f1 \ulnone :
\f0   ---\
\
\pard\tx1560\tx1985\pardeftab720\partightenfactor0
\cf0 \expnd0\expndtw0\kerning0
\uc0\u922 \u913 \u921 \u929 \u927 \u931     :
\b0      \uc0\u931 \u935 \u917 \u916 \u927 \u925  \u913 \u921 \u920 \u929 \u921 \u927 \u931 . \u932 \u921 \u931  \u924 \u917 \u931 \u919 \u924 \u914 \u929 \u921 \u925 \u917 \u931 -\u913 \u928 \u927 \u915 \u917 \u933 \u924 \u913 \u932 \u921 \u925 \u917 \u931  \u937 \u929 \u917 \u931  \u920 \u913  \u922 \u913 \u932 \u913 \u931 \u932 \u917 \u921  \u928 \u913 \u929 \u927 \u916 \u921 \u922 \u913  \u925 \u917 \u934 \u917 \u923 \u937 \u916 \u919 \u931  \u924 \u917  \u928 \u921 \u920 \u913 \u925 \u927 \u932 \u919 \u932 \u913  \u917 \u922 \u916 \u919 \u923 \u937 \u931 \u919 \u931  \u927 \u924 \u914 \u929 \u937 \u925 , \u922 \u933 \u929 \u921 \u937 \u931 , \u931 \u932 \u913  \u915 \u933 \u929 \u937  \u927 \u929 \u917 \u921 \u925 \u913 .\

\b \uc0\u913 \u925 \u917 \u924 \u927 \u921  :    
\b0 \uc0\u924 \u917 \u932 \u913 \u914 \u923 \u919 \u932 \u927 \u921  \u913 \u931 \u920 \u917 \u925 \u917 \u921 \u931 . \u932 \u921 \u931  \u924 \u917 \u931 \u919 \u924 \u914 \u929 \u921 \u925 \u917 \u931 -\u913 \u928 \u927 \u915 \u917 \u933 \u924 \u913 \u932 \u921 \u925 \u917 \u931  \u937 \u929 \u917 \u931  \u920 \u913  \u931 \u932 \u929 \u913 \u934 \u927 \u933 \u925  \u931 \u917  \u925 \u927 \u932 \u921 \u937 \u925  \u916 \u921 \u917 \u933 \u920 \u933 \u925 \u931 \u917 \u937 \u925  \u917 \u937 \u931  \u931 \u935 \u917 \u916 \u927 \u925  \u924 \u917 \u932 \u929 \u921 \u927 \u921 . \u917 \u926 \u913 \u931 \u920 \u917 \u925 \u919 \u931 \u919  \u932 \u927  \u914 \u929 \u913 \u916 \u933 .\

\b \uc0\u920 \u917 \u929 \u924 \u927 \u922 \u929 \u913 \u931 \u921 \u913    :    
\b0 \uc0\u935 \u937 \u929 \u921 \u931  \u913 \u926 \u921 \u927 \u923 \u927 \u915 \u919  \u924 \u917 \u932 \u913 \u914 \u927 \u923 \u919  \u922 \u913 \u921  \u920 \u913  \u922 \u933 \u924 \u913 \u925 \u920 \u917 \u921  \u913 \u928 \u927  14\'b0C \u917 \u937 \u931  32\'b0C.  
\f1 \

\f0\b \uc0\u920 \kerning1\expnd0\expndtw0 \uc0\u927 \u923 \u937 \u931 \u919     :       
\b0 \uc0\u913 \u931 \u920 \u917 \u925 \u919 \u931 -\u924 \u917 \u932 \u929 \u921 \u913  \u917 \u937 \u931  \u932 \u913  8.000
\f1 FT
\f0 .\

\b \expnd0\expndtw0\kerning0
\uc0\u927 \u929 \u913 \u932 \u927 \u932 \u919 \u932 \u913   :       
\b0 \uc0\u922 \u913 \u923 \u919 .
\b \cf2 \kerning1\expnd0\expndtw0                             \
\
                                    \cf0  \ul \uc0\u928 \u929 \u927 \u927 \u928 \u932 \u921 \u922 \u919  \u922 \u913 \u921 \u929 \u927 \u933  \u917 \u928 \u927 \u924 \u917 \u925 \u919 \u931  \u919 \u924 \u917 \u929 \u913 \u931 \
\ulnone \uc0\u921 \u931 \u935 \u933 \u931   :      \u913 \u928 \u927  02-
\f1 0
\f0 6-2022/0000
\f1 C
\f0  \uc0\u917 \u937 \u931  02-
\f1 0
\f0 6-202
\f1 2
\f0 /2400
\f1 C
\f0 \
\
\expnd0\expndtw0\kerning0
\uc0\u922 \u913 \u921 \u929 \u927 \u931     :
\b0      \uc0\u931 \u935 \u917 \u916 \u927 \u925  \u913 \u921 \u920 \u929 \u921 \u927 \u931 . \u932 \u921 \u931  \u924 \u917 \u931 \u919 \u924 \u914 \u929 \u921 \u925 \u917 \u931 -\u913 \u928 \u927 \u915 \u917 \u933 \u924 \u913 \u932 \u921 \u925 \u917 \u931  \u937 \u929 \u917 \u931  \u920 \u913  \u922 \u913 \u932 \u913 \u931 \u932 \u917 \u921  \u928 \u929 \u927 \u931 \u922 \u913 \u921 \u929 \u913  \u923 \u921 \u915 \u927  \u925 \u917 \u934 \u917 \u923 \u937 \u916 \u919 \u931 .\

\b \uc0\u913 \u925 \u917 \u924 \u927 \u921  :    
\b0 \uc0\u924 \u917 \u932 \u913 \u914 \u923 \u919 \u932 \u927 \u921  \u913 \u931 \u920 \u917 \u925 \u917 \u921 \u931 . \u932 \u921 \u931  \u924 \u917 \u931 \u919 \u924 \u914 \u929 \u921 \u925 \u917 \u931 -\u913 \u928 \u927 \u915 \u917 \u933 \u924 \u913 \u932 \u921 \u925 \u917 \u931  \u937 \u929 \u917 \u931  \u920 \u913  \u931 \u932 \u929 \u913 \u934 \u927 \u933 \u925  \u931 \u917  \u925 \u927 \u932 \u921 \u937 \u925  \u916 \u921 \u917 \u933 \u920 \u933 \u925 \u931 \u917 \u937 \u925  \u917 \u937 \u931  \u931 \u935 \u917 \u916 \u927 \u925  \u924 \u917 \u932 \u929 \u921 \u927 \u921 . \u917 \u926 \u913 \u931 \u920 \u917 \u925 \u919 \u931 \u919  \u932 \u927  \u914 \u929 \u913 \u916 \u933 .\

\b \uc0\u920 \u917 \u929 \u924 \u927 \u922 \u929 \u913 \u931 \u921 \u913    :    
\b0 \uc0\u935 \u937 \u929 \u921 \u931  \u913 \u926 \u921 \u927 \u923 \u927 \u915 \u919  \u924 \u917 \u932 \u913 \u914 \u927 \u923 \u919  \u922 \u913 \u921  \u920 \u913  \u922 \u933 \u924 \u913 \u925 \u920 \u917 \u921  \u913 \u928 \u927  15\'b0C \u917 \u937 \u931  33\'b0C.  
\f1 \

\f0\b \uc0\u920 \kerning1\expnd0\expndtw0 \uc0\u927 \u923 \u937 \u931 \u919     :      
\b0 \uc0\u913 \u931 \u920 \u917 \u925 \u919 \u931  \u917 \u937 \u931  \u932 \u913  8.000
\f1 FT
\f0 .\

\b \expnd0\expndtw0\kerning0
\uc0\u927 \u929 \u913 \u932 \u927 \u932 \u919 \u932 \u913   :      
\b0 \uc0\u922 \u913 \u923 \u919 .
\b \

\f2\b0 \cf2 \
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Written in an open Windows command prompt (`cmd.exe`):

```
ren "D:\bat\SO\72671278" 72671278.rtf
start "" "D:\bat\SO\72671278.rtf"
```

The latter command opens the file in `wordpad.exe`<sup>1</sup> (formatting lost here, sorry):

```
FOGR93 LGTS 010330
ΠΡΟΓΝΩΣΗ ΚΑΙΡΟΥ Α/Δ ΘΕΣΣΑΛΟΝΙΚΗΣ


ΕΠΙΚΙΝΔΥΝΑ ΦΑΙΝΟΜΕΝΑ:  ---

ΚΑΙΡΟΣ    :     ΣΧΕΔΟΝ ΑΙΘΡΙΟΣ. ΤΙΣ ΜΕΣΗΜΒΡΙΝΕΣ-ΑΠΟΓΕΥΜΑΤΙΝΕΣ ΩΡΕΣ ΘΑ ΚΑΤΑΣΤΕΙ ΠΑΡΟΔΙΚΑ ΝΕΦΕΛΩΔΗΣ ΜΕ ΠΙΘΑΝΟΤΗΤΑ ΕΚΔΗΛΩΣΗΣ ΟΜΒΡΩΝ, ΚΥΡΙΩΣ, ΣΤΑ ΓΥΡΩ ΟΡΕΙΝΑ.
ΑΝΕΜΟΙ :    ΜΕΤΑΒΛΗΤΟΙ ΑΣΘΕΝΕΙΣ. ΤΙΣ ΜΕΣΗΜΒΡΙΝΕΣ-ΑΠΟΓΕΥΜΑΤΙΝΕΣ ΩΡΕΣ ΘΑ ΣΤΡΑΦΟΥΝ ΣΕ ΝΟΤΙΩΝ ΔΙΕΥΘΥΝΣΕΩΝ ΕΩΣ ΣΧΕΔΟΝ ΜΕΤΡΙΟΙ. ΕΞΑΣΘΕΝΗΣΗ ΤΟ ΒΡΑΔΥ.
ΘΕΡΜΟΚΡΑΣΙΑ   :    ΧΩΡΙΣ ΑΞΙΟΛΟΓΗ ΜΕΤΑΒΟΛΗ ΚΑΙ ΘΑ ΚΥΜΑΝΘΕΙ ΑΠΟ 14°C ΕΩΣ 32°C.  
ΘΟΛΩΣΗ    :       ΑΣΘΕΝΗΣ-ΜΕΤΡΙΑ ΕΩΣ ΤΑ 8.000FT.
ΟΡΑΤΟΤΗΤΑ  :       ΚΑΛΗ.                            

                                     ΠΡΟΟΠΤΙΚΗ ΚΑΙΡΟΥ ΕΠΟΜΕΝΗΣ ΗΜΕΡΑΣ
ΙΣΧΥΣ  :      ΑΠΟ 02-06-2022/0000C ΕΩΣ 02-06-2022/2400C

ΚΑΙΡΟΣ    :     ΣΧΕΔΟΝ ΑΙΘΡΙΟΣ. ΤΙΣ ΜΕΣΗΜΒΡΙΝΕΣ-ΑΠΟΓΕΥΜΑΤΙΝΕΣ ΩΡΕΣ ΘΑ ΚΑΤΑΣΤΕΙ ΠΡΟΣΚΑΙΡΑ ΛΙΓΟ ΝΕΦΕΛΩΔΗΣ.
ΑΝΕΜΟΙ :    ΜΕΤΑΒΛΗΤΟΙ ΑΣΘΕΝΕΙΣ. ΤΙΣ ΜΕΣΗΜΒΡΙΝΕΣ-ΑΠΟΓΕΥΜΑΤΙΝΕΣ ΩΡΕΣ ΘΑ ΣΤΡΑΦΟΥΝ ΣΕ ΝΟΤΙΩΝ ΔΙΕΥΘΥΝΣΕΩΝ ΕΩΣ ΣΧΕΔΟΝ ΜΕΤΡΙΟΙ. ΕΞΑΣΘΕΝΗΣΗ ΤΟ ΒΡΑΔΥ.
ΘΕΡΜΟΚΡΑΣΙΑ   :    ΧΩΡΙΣ ΑΞΙΟΛΟΓΗ ΜΕΤΑΒΟΛΗ ΚΑΙ ΘΑ ΚΥΜΑΝΘΕΙ ΑΠΟ 15°C ΕΩΣ 33°C.  
ΘΟΛΩΣΗ    :      ΑΣΘΕΝΗΣ ΕΩΣ ΤΑ 8.000FT.
ΟΡΑΤΟΤΗΤΑ  :      ΚΑΛΗ.
```

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>`C:\Program Files\Windows NT\Accessories\wordpad.exe`</sup>

Comment: thanks. This works but still cant pass the text into powerpoint with vba. It continues to pass it with the older form

Comment: in mac terminal using `textutil -convert txt PathName/*.rtf` easily convert to txt and open it with `cat`